# Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have created an endpoint and when i am sending a request on the endpoint i am receiving the object for the offices but when it comes to the recipient i got an error of SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0 and when i checked on the project's log from where i am getting the request it gives me an error of StatusCodeError: 400.but when i am sending the request using postman it doesn't give any error it worked fine. here is the code of the endpoint.

```
const { growthfilemsdb } = require('../config');
const { code } = require('../utils/reportUtils');
const { getBearerToken, tokenValidator } = require('../utils/http');
const update = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const bearerToken = getBearerToken({ headers: req.headers })
    if (tokenValidator(bearerToken)) {
      const officeID = req.body.officeId;
      const recipientID = req.body.recipientId;

      const data = {
        requestBody: req.body,
      };
      if (
        req.body.hasOwnProperty('officeId') &&
        req.body.template === 'office'
      ) {
        const officeDb = await growthfilemsdb
          .collection('Offices')
          .doc(officeID)
          .set(data.requestBody, { merge: false });

        return res.status(code.ok).send({ success: true, message: `Success` });
      } else if (
        req.body.hasOwnProperty('recipientId') &&
        req.body.hasOwnProperty('officeId') &&
        req.body.template === 'recipient'
      ) {
        const recipientData = await growthfilemsdb
          .collection('Offices')
          .doc(officeID)
          .collection('Recipients')
          .doc(recipientID)
          .set(data.requestBody, { merge: false });

        return res.status(code.ok).send({ success: true, message: `Success` });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(code.forbidden).send('Forbidden');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res
      .status(code.internalServerError)
      .send({ success: false, message: `Internal Server Error` });
  }
};
module.exports = { update };
```

and i have used this code in the index.js file as in this way

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const updateRecord = require('./api/updateApi');
require('dotenv').config();
app
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

    app.put('/activity', updateRecord.update);
```

this is the error i got when i am sending request

```
StatusCodeError: 400 - "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Bad Request</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
    at new StatusCodeError (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-native/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-native/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-native/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at Request.self.callback (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
```

and this is the error i am getting when i am receiving

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)
    at parse (/worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
```

Comment: May be an aphostrophe or a new line in the returned result ?

Comment: i couldn't get it

Comment: @CoskunOzogul but on the sender project, I am only getting statusCode 400 error nothing more

Comment: show us your offices object json, which were sent.

Comment: i am not able to send because of limitation of comment length

Comment: @RatulSharker i am able to store office document

Comment: In order to debug this issue, you should log what you are receiving at the Cloud Function. Apart from being able to see exactly what you are sending from your code, you will be able to compare it with what you send from Postman.